# I imported my private key into blockchain.info but it says 'no free outputs to spend'?

Tags: blockchain.info, private-key-import

After two days of researching I finally got my private key! However when I import it in Blockchain, it says 'no free outputs to spend'. How do I fix this?

Comment: This may sound stupid, but are you sure that you imported the correct address? If you are sure, have you checked on e.g. http://blockexplorer.com that the address did receive the transaction that should have funded it?